# Windows 10 "We can't set up a mobile hotspot" with one/two wifi adapters

Tags: wireless-hotspot

Whenever I try to use the new Win10 mobile hotspot, it says it can't set it up. I have one usb wifi adapter plugged in (no ethernet) and plugging in a second usb adapter doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you're using exactly hardware and mobile device wise for the hot spot and what you are using to connect to the hot spot as well??

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Device Manager and disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the wireless network adapter's Power Management setting.

Comment: Can you clarify how this would solve the problem?

Comment: @fixer1234 I wouldn't know "how" - only the Microsoft people will know. But this solved my problem.

Comment: Can you post a link to where you learned about this, or where people can find more information?

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't have any link for this. I was having this issue for the second time, and the solution was something I remembered off the top of my head. So I just posted it here in case anyone else encounters the same issue and arrives here (like me when I was looking for a solution).